# How to group quantities in a period of time

Tags: sql

Im trying to group quantities regarding a time or period, i have the next table

SALES
SALES_DATE
SALES_ITEM
SALES_QUANTITY

The query that im doing it's

```
SELECT DATE,ITEM,SUM(QUANTITY) 
FROM SALES 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN "DATE1" AND "DATE2";
```

The problem is that i dont need the DATE to appear, if i look for the sales of october it should appear the sum of october without showing the date... Thank you very much for your help

Example:
What i get...

```
DATE         ITEM               SALES
2012-06-12   14152              7
2012-06-14   14152              15
2012-06-16   14157              25
```

What i need: query between 06-12 and 06-16

```
ITEM         SALES
14152        22
14157        25
```

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the sum by month, you can include that in the group by expression.  Here is one way:

```
SELECT extract(year from DATE) as yr, extract(month from date) as mon, ITEM, SUM(QUANTITY) 
FROM SALES 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN "DATE1" AND "DATE2"
group by extract(year from DATE), extract(month from date)
order by 1, 2
```

Although `extract` is standard SQL, not all databases support it.  For instance, you might use `to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM')` in Oracle or `datepart(month, date)` in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon i just tried it and worked perfectly thank you very much  :)